# Having issues with Improper Fraction output in Java

Tags: java, class, return-value, fractions

I believe I am doing this right, but I am having issues with my ImproperFraction method in my fraction class outputting properly. It is just to output wither or not the fraction is improper, doesn't have to be anything special.

```
 public boolean ImproperFraction(Fraction otherObject1){

     if( numerator > denominator) {

          System.out.println("Your fraction is improper and cannot be reduced"); 
          Fraction otherFraction = (Fraction)otherObject1;
          return ((numerator == otherFraction.numerator) && 
             (denominator == otherFraction.denominator));
       }

     else if(numerator <= denominator) {
         System.out.println("Your fraction is proper and has been reduced");
         return false;
       } 

     else {
       return false;
     }     
   }
```

In the main class:

```
 System.out.println(ImproperFraction);
```

The only thing that it is doing is returning false, even though the fraction I put in for it is improper. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Where is numerator and denominator coming from?

Comment: Why are you comparing one Franction number with another Fraction number to determine if it's improper fraction or not? Should just compare the numerator and denominator of the fraction that is being tested.

Comment: Is this a method in the `Fraction` class?  If so, there's no need to pass in a second fraction, to test whether the first one is improper.  Maybe you should get rid of `otherObject1` and just return `true` after you print the message inside the `if` block.

Comment: Theres no way (numerator>denominator || numerator<=denominator) could be false. So are you positive it is only returning false and never printing out those print statements?

Comment: Improper fraction is when numerator is equal or greater than denominator.

Comment: Can you post the full code sample including the exact fraction you're passing into the method?

Comment: Is this really in your main class? This should being throwing an error  System.out.println(ImproperFraction);

Comment: Nah, she's probably got a line that says something like `boolean ImproperFraction = someFraction.ImproperFraction(someOtherFraction);`

Comment: Here is the link for the entire code, it was too much of a pain to try and figure out how to post it here. http://pastebin.com/KnXwpeXB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, now that you've shown your entire code - it seems that you're not actually calling the `ImproperFraction` method anywhere.

You've got a static boolean variable called `ImproperFraction` which you never actually set, so it's always false.  And in the line `System.out.println(ImproperFraction)`, you're printing that variable.  But you never call the `ImproperFraction` method, so the code that you've posted in the actual question (not the pastebin) never runs.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're only returning true if the numerator and denominator of the current `Fraction` (the `this` object) are equal to the numerator and denominator of the fraction that you passed in.  That first block should just say

```
if (numerator >= denominator) {
    System.out.println( "This fraction is improper" );
    return true;
}
```

and not bother comparing numerators and denominators with `otherObject1`.

In fact, you should probably not bother passing in `otherObject1` at all.  You don't need it.